# sudoku parallelization with MPI

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi, depth-first-search, sudoku

I want to parallelize my sudoku solver program with MPI. The current serial code relies on backtracking with depth-first search. I did some research, but I am still not sure how to do it.
Some say that program must do a breadth-first search to get some data in master process and then use slave processes with this data. So that the slave processes will do depth-first search using this data.

Also I saw that some depth-first search parallelization examples use work sharing or work stealing methods. But in case of sudoku, I am not sure that using this technique can handle process relations, work queue and process size because of sudoku's solving methodology.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate question:
[Parallelizing a sudoku solver][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853755/how-to-parallelize-sudoku-solver-using-grand-central-dispatch

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer pertaining to Sudoku, more to the fact that you specify your serial algorithm uses a depth-first search. Depth-first search is a problem that is known to be [difficult to parallelize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_algorithm), despite not appearing to be 'inherently serial'.

There are parallel DFS implementations however. For example this [1987 paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.3535&rep=rep1&type=pdf) presents a parallel DFS algorithm. The general principle is that each processor searches a different set of paths until it reaches a leaf (or an arbitrary search depth), and when it has completed it's subset of paths, chooses a new unexplored branch.

If you are keen to implement a parallel DFS I would recommend reading that article and having a go implementing that algorithm. However I think there are probably more intelligent parallel sudoku algorithms that do not use DFS, for example it could be solved using Constraint Propagation.